# PHP imagecopyresampled + how to get the best results

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have the following working fine:

1. User uploads an image and the image is resized using imagecopyresampled and imagejpeg (keeping the proportions) so it fits the cropping DIV.
2. The user then crops the image with JCrop and then the resized above image is then cut into the 5 required crop sizes using imagecopyresampled and imagejpeg.

---

The problem I've found is by cropping from the resized image doesn't take advantage of the very original image that is often larger and better quality.

So I want to display an image that fits the DIV but crop from the very original image to get the best quality.

When I just change the cropping to the original image the crop is of the wrong part of the image as the sizing is different. This is obvious I assume. Diff sized images.

---

How can I display an image that fits the DIV for Jcrop but then actually crop off the original which is often larger?

Ideas I'm testing:

- displaying the original image in the DIV (not resized by php but resized by CSS). I'm not sure if this will make any difference.
- try to use some math based equation to get the correct crop. Unsure how I'll do this currently.

Ideas would be great...
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would go with the maths based solution if you have to work with the full sized image server side. Re-scaling in the browser directly or through CSS is not ideal IMO and differs greatly between browsers. If you use the math based option you could calculate the co-ordinates on the smaller image crop and scale that up to get the right portion of the original image.

On a side note you may find (depending on the image sizes and image types you allow uploaded) that copying and resizing on the PHP side is very CPU and memory intensive. A png file for example of roughly 1024 x 768 in high resolution can take up to 60MB to 80MB of RAM just to resize (per image re-sample due to compression on the png file) and that is regardless of which PHP image manipulation modules ([ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), etc) you use. There is no perfect way to handle image uploads from the PHP server end (other than throwing heaps of memory and CPU at the task). There are some good jQuery solutions however that resize on the client side before the upload (e.g. [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/), etc) which means you will only be working with a reduced size image on the server side. There are also some JQuery client side cropping scripts which are good. Either way a combination of PHP and jQuery would be the best IMO.